# .bbl file not created by BibLaTeX; no preexisting BibTeX conflict

Tags: biblatex, biber, ubuntu, bbl

I run the following code:

```
% !BIB TS-program = biber
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibshort.bib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
\cite{onishchik}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

The file bibshort.bib is in the same folder. I am running TeXStudio via TeX Live on Ubuntu 14.04, with a "Build & View" code of

```
txs:///pdflatex | txs:///biber | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///pdflatex | txs:///view
```

There are no old auxiliary files starting with the name of my file in the same directory. I did

```
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra
sudo apt-get install texlive-bibtex-extra biber
```

just in case, but these were already updated. LaTeX and BibTeX both seem to be doing fine, on the other hand.

```
which biber
```

returns

```
/usr/bin/biber
```

The log for my document is as follows:

```
: No file mintexbib.bbl.
line 8: Citation 'onishchik' on page 1 undefined
line 9: Empty bibliography
: There were undefined references.
: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) mintexbib(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

The document produced reads "Hi! **[onishchik ]**" and this name is a real citation key in the bibshort.bib that lives in the same folder.

What can I do to get a bibliography?

Comment: Can you show us the entry labelled onishik?

Comment: Please re-check your editor configuration against [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/154751/35864). Can you find a `.blg` file in document directory, if so what does it say? (Please note that the TeX live distribution from the Ubuntu repositories is often a bit behind.)

Comment: @book{onishchik,
Author = {Onishchik, Arkadi L},
Date-Added = {2015-03-26 11:58:10 PM +0000},
Date-Modified = {2015-03-26 23:58:46 +0000},
Publisher = {Johann Ambrosius Barth},
Title = {Topology of transitive transformation groups},
Year = {1994}}

Comment: Not at computer right now, but will do this tonight, @moewe. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, at my computer. There is no .blg file corresponding to the file in this directory. Another .blg file that I produced from this distribution starts with "This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2013/Debian)."

Comment: My configuration matches what is on that page. I had configured Quick Build to do PiDFTeX / Biber / PDFTeX. I switched it to LaTeX / Biber / LaTeX to exactly match that page. Now when I compile, I get no errors, but the page output is the same. I took out all the auxiliary files and the PDF, and when I tried to compile again, it gave me an error that the PDF file had been deleted.

Comment: Mhhhh, the other `.blg` file comes from BibTeX and not Biber. Can you try running the commands manually from the command line (cf. [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/35864))? If you don't get to see a `.blg` something is seriously wrong, either Biber is not installed, got corrupted or it is not called properly.

Comment: I erased all aux files and did latex / biber / latex in a terminal, and it compiled fine. Now pdflatex / biber / pdflatex in TeXStudio is producing fine results. I have no idea why it's working now—I didn't change *anything*—but anyway, it's working! Thank you for your help and patience!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by deleting auxiliary files and compiling again (see comment above).

Comment: Seems legit, since the problem isn't reproducible. This isn't the first time I'd deleted the auxiliary files, though, so I'm not sure why it only worked this time.